# How can I create a fake window?

Tags: unity, window-manager, window

**Problem:**

As soon as I close all windows, my system freezes and becomes non-responsive.

**Workaround:**

I would like to create a fake window that is open but not visible in the window switcher, Unity launcher (sidebar). I want this window to prevent my system from freezing and becoming non-responsive.

**Question:**

How can I create such a window?

Comment: A "normal" window (other than one of Unity's special ones like the launcher etc, or the desktop itself)  either needs to be transient or a "standalone" window, and thus will be represented in the launcher. Apart from that, I wouldn't have my system like that without solving the issue.

Comment: isn't what you try to do a (bad) workaround to a problem that might be properly solved by other means?

Comment: Guys, you are right. I wish I knew how to fix this properly. But I have no idea how to debug this problem.